# .NET Azure.Identity SDK network timeout

Tags: c#, .net, azure

In .NET 7 app I am trying to use Azure Identity. However, I frequently get `The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:00:01. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.`

I am trying to increase the timeout but it does not work. How to properly increase the timeout

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder.ConfigureDefaults(options =>
    {
        options.Retry.NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    });
    
    // Add a Storage account client
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureBlobStorage"));

    // Use DefaultAzureCredential by default
    clientBuilder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
    {
        Retry = { NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) }
    }));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to, the process is taking longer time than usual.

By setting the increase the timeout  `NetworkTimeout` property of the `RetryOptions` object in the code.

> You are setting the `NetworkTimeout` property of the `RetryOptions` object in two places.

- In the `ConfigureDefaults` method of the `clientBuilder` object, and in the `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions` object that is passed to the `UseCredential` method of the `clientBuilder` object.

You have to set the `NetworkTimeout` property in one place.

By setting only in `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions` object will suffice the request.

The below are the NuGets to be installed.

[image]

**Code**

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder.ConfigureDefaults(options =>
    {
    });
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureBlobStorage"));
    clientBuilder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
    {
        Retry = { NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) }
    }));
});
```

[image]

> You can also add the requestTimeout="00:20:00 in the configuration file in your slots sites/wwwroot folder.

[image]

For further information refer to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet) and [Github Issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/33124).

Comment: Your solution does not work as the timeout is still The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:00:01. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.

Comment: One reason for this issue is that the NetworkTimeout property is being overridden by another setting. You may want to check if there are any other settings that are affecting the timeout value.
And Another reason is that the timeout is being triggered by a different operation. You need to check the specific operation that is causing the timeout and see if there are any other settings that can be adjusted to increase the timeout.